# Handling IE pop-up with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have an Excel VBA macro that interacts with an intranet site through Internet Explorer to loop through a list of customers, open the customers profile, update a field and save the changes.

The problem I am running into is that when I save the changes to the customers profile there is a pop-up window in the web application asking me to confirm the changes to their profile and i can't figure out how to programatically click the "OK" in the pop-up. When I click the save button, the javascript executes a function call for submitting the changes.

Send keys won't work because the code will not execute the next line until the pop-up is confirmed.  i tried some other solutions mentioned and couldn't get them to work correctly (the javascript parts are new to me).

Any help in figuring out how to programatically click "OK" to let my code run in peace would be greatly appreciated.

VBA code:

```
    'pulling up edit user profile link
    s = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(4).href
    objIE.navigate s

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Adding value to customers profile and saving changes
    objIE.document.all.Item("Contact_Id").Value = Sheets("List").Range("c" & n).Value
    objIE.document.all.Item("submitBn").Click

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Java script function the submit button is calling:

```
function doNextPage() {
if (checkFormInputForEnglish(document.editProfileForm)) {
    if(validateForm()){
        if(confirm("Do\x20you\x20want\x20to\x20submit\x20the\x20changes\x3F")) {
            document.editProfileForm.submitBn.disabled = true;
            document.editProfileForm.submit();
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this `Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("doNextPage()", "JavaScript")` instead of `.click` ? (not sure if that is correct syntax, found it here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?9690-Solved-call-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Use selenium instead. You have easier control over windows and can switch between new and prior/previous smoothly.

Comment: Try this if @Kubie 's suggestion didn't work `IE.Document.Script.eval("doNextPage()")`

Comment: I aslo tried @Kubie's suggestion before posting this and it calls and executes the script, but doesn;t click through the pop-up.

Comment: I tried @de.vina's suggestion but it gives me a run-time error "object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @MMWW are you able to `sendkeys` after using this approach tho?

Comment: Ok.. what kind of pop-up does it give? Is it similar to MsgBox or is it a customized one? If it's customized, you may try to execute the function and then hide the element afterwards. Here is a sample code `IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ok")(0).Style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: @Kubie - No, I can;t use Sendkeys because the VBA won't move forward until after the javascript is done running (ie.  clicking the pop-up).

Comment: @de.vina - same issue here.  i can't get that line of code to run because the javascript is still running.  it's a small message box in the web app that is just "OK" or "Cancel"

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA,

focus the submit button by `objIE.document.all.Item("submitBn").Focus`

And Then use `SendKeys "~"` to Click the button.

So here VBA won't be engaged. Now, Detect the (HTML)popup by checking if the HTML popup code is Visible/Exist